# Mouse usb stopped after update

Tags: 11.04, mouse, freeze, updates

I have a `Sony Vaio CW23FX` and use a wireless usb mouse and it worked perfect until the 2 days ago. Now the mouse is a little crazy.

When I use Chromium it works fine, but with I try to click ther unity bar or other application or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or superbutton dont work  (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>left</kbd> works). If I power off the mouse and use the touchpad, back to works fine, if I back for the usb mouse for a little time works fine and then bug again.

It's like the mouse freezes in the window I'm using.

I've read this https://askubuntu.com/questions/60647/mouse-randomly-clicks-jumps-and-blocks-clicking-keyboard-then-also-messes-up and tried the  `xwininfo -all`, and returns `Can't grab the mouse`.

What can I do?

Comment: Was that an xorg update? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: I guess can be a xorg update.... I already tried to reboot

Comment: Try reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all` using Synaptic.

Comment: Worked!!! Thanks!! now the xwininfo -all is printing right!

Comment: No problem, this is the most common solution to problems related to updates!

Comment: I thought it was me alone. Thank god somebody else had the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all` using Synaptic.

*Copied from comments because some people (like me) never look at the comments if there is no answer when they are having the same problem...*